# Как заставить Google Navigation выводить только один маршрут?

Tags: google-maps, android

Внутри своего приложения я запускаю навигацию от Google следующим образом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + mCity));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Такой вызов должен построить маршрут от моего текущего местоположения по GPS до города назначения. Но зачастую приложение предлагает мне выбрать один из нескольких маршрутов, как показано на скриншоте ниже. Как можно принудительно заставить его всегда выводить только один маршрут, без возможности выбора?

[image]

Comment: написать свой навигатор?

Comment: @KoVadim, это достаточно трудоемкая задача. Может быть, есть способ проще?

Comment: я не вижу причин, по которым не нужно давать пользователю выбор. Пусть выбирает себе маршрут. Мало чего.

Comment: @KoVadim, причина здесь одна - необходимо кликнуть по экрану. В моем случае это недопустимо. Нужно просто запустить навигацию, чтобы пользователю не нужно было касаться экрана.

Comment: Согласно [оффициальной документации](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents), такого нет. Можно выбрать только вид транспорта и координаты.